# How to add a custom nose plugin to the `nosetests` command

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, nose, nosetests

So I'm very noob in dealing with nose plugins.

I've been searching a lot but docs regarding nose plugins seem scarce. 
I read and tried what's in the following links to try to write a simple nose plugin 
and run it with `nosetests`, without success:

1. https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_init_plugin/init_plugin.html
2. https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/writing.html

I don't want to write my own test-runner or run the tests from any other script (via `run(argv=argv, suite=suite(), ...)`), 
like they do in the first link.

I wrote a file `myplugin.py` with a class like this:

```
import os
from nose.plugins import Plugin

class MyCustomPlugin(Plugin):
    name = 'myplugin'

    def options(self, parser, env=os.environ):
        parser.add_option('--custom-path', action='store',
                          dest='custom_path', default=None,
                          help='Specify path to widget config file')

    def configure(self, options, conf):
        if options.custom_path:
            self.make_some_configs(options.custom_path)
            self.enabled = True

    def make_some_configs(self, path):
        # do some stuff based on the given path

    def begin(self):
        print 'Maybe print some useful stuff...'
        # do some more stuff
```

and added a `setup.py` like this:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
except ImportError:
    import distribute_setup
    distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    ...
    install_requires=['nose==1.3.0'],
    py_modules=['myplugin'],
    entry_points={
      'nose.plugins.1.3.0': [
        'myplugin = myplugin:MyCustomPlugin'
      ]
    }
)
```

Both files are in the same directory.

Every time I run `nosetests --custom-path [path]`, I get:

```
nosetests: error: no such option: --custom-path
```

From the links mentioned above, I thought that's all that was required to register and enable a custom plugin. 
But it seems that, either I'm doing something really wrong, or nose's docs are outdated.

Can someone please point me the correct way to register and enable a plugin, that I can use with `nosetests`?

Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want the `nose` version in `entry_points` in `setup.py`.  Just use `nose.plugins.0.10` as the docs say.  The dotted version in the entry point name is not so much a `nose` version as a plugin API version.